# Access to a variable defined in main

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need some inputs on the best way to access var1 defined in main in func2 ,program flow is like below..please advise

```
func2():

 #need to access var1 in func2


func1():

   func2()

def main():

  var1
  func1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mark the variables as [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) in both functions.

```
def func2():
    global var1
    print var1

    var1 = "World"

def func1():
    func2()

def main():
    global var1
    var1 = "Hello"
    func1()

    print var1
```

Output:

```
Hello
World
```

---

With the question answered as it was asked, there are better ways to go about this.

- If you only need to *read* the variable in `func2`, then pass it as a parameter, as [Joran Beasley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14097461/119527) shows.
- If you need to get values back from `func2`, then it makes more sense to return a value.
- If you have to read/write a variable all over the place, you should reconsider your design. Or, consider wrapping the functions up in a `class`, and make it a member variable.

Comment: you got the flow wrong..i need to access in func2 called from func1...also any other better way other than global approach

Comment: @user1934146 It's the same, I just simplified the example. And No: If you want to *write* to a variable with a non-local scope, it has to be marked global.

Comment: +1 since this works ... but i try to avoid globals when i can ...  but your comments make it a big +1

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using parameters instead of globals ... but either should work

```
def func2(value=None):
 print value
 #need to access var1 in func2


def func1(var_val=None):

   func2(var_val)

def main():

  var1 = "hello";
  func1(var1)
```

or class level static variables

```
class config:
   var1=None

def func2(value=None):
 print config.var1
 #need to access var1 in func2


def func1():

   func2()

def main():

  config.var1 = "hello";
  func1()
```

Comment: But this only works if you want to *read* the variable. What if you want to modify it?

Comment: then i would recommend a return value ... but yeah global may simplify it ... but its just not good form imho ... at least use some kind of package namespace or static class variable ... :/

Comment: Yep, I agree - I was just answering the question though.

Comment: +1 Class-static variables make for an interesting way of organizing globals. I like it.